# How to align sections defined in the default linker script?

Tags: ld, linker-scripts

`ld` has currently two ways to extend the default linker script that is compiled in:

1. by supplying an additional linker script on the command line without using the `-T` option (i.e., just like object files);
2. by supplying a linker script with `-T` containing an [`INSERT (BEFORE | AFTER)` command](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Miscellaneous-Commands.html#index-INSERT).

I've been trying to use these to add a `MEMORY` map, align some sections of the default linker script and add symbols, e.g.,

```
MEMORY
{
  ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = $(1), LENGTH = 128M
}
SECTIONS {
  . = ALIGN(4*1024*1024);
  __init_start = . ;
} INSERT BEFORE .init
```

Some parts work just fine (the memory map, creating the `__init_start` at the right offset/alignment) but the offset of the `.init` section that comes "after" this is not changed. I've tried various variants to no avail. Am I doing it wrong or is this currently simply not possible? Maybe it's another use case for the [proposed extension syntax](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26404).

If it's currently impossible then I would like to know the reason, i.e., why many attributes can be overwritten but the addresses of existing sections are not changed by location counter updates?